# In a 3 tier (or more) PKI, is it permissible that a Name Constraint only be defined on the middle tier?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

I'm working with an Issuing CA that doesn't support name constraints that are defined at a higher level.

Assuming that it issues certificates that are compliant with the Name Constraints that are defined, would this be an issue with clients that validate the chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't guarantee that everyone does it right, but the entire certificate chain up to a trusted root should be validated to be valid for the certificate name.  As long as the only certs generated are valid, it should be ok, but if an intermediate CA signs something it isn't authorized to sign, then the validation should fail as the intermediate CA isn't trusted to perform that signature.